# selenium как из тегов достать значение

Tags: selenium

как отсюда достать значение с помощью selenium?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("click"));
    //System.out.println(e.getAttribute("href"));


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\giosan777\\Desktop\\selenium-2.40.0\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.lider-bet.com/web/ka/playVolt");
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.switchTo().frame("frame");
    //WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("hash-table"));
    //System.out.println(element.getAttribute("hash-table"));

    List<WebElement> TRCollection = driver.findElement(By.className("hash-table"))
            .findElements(By.tagName("tbody"));

    for (WebElement tr : TRCollection)
    {
        List<WebElement> TDCollection = tr.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for (WebElement td: TDCollection)
        {
            System.out.println(td.getText());
        }
    }


    driver.quit();      //close Chrome

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, вот так:

```
String elementval = driver.findElement(By.id("input_name")).getAttribute("value");
```

Только подставьте свой селектор.